# Storing code snippets in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-snippets

I'm a recent semi-convert to Eclipse after 20 years of using vi and gvim.  One of the things I miss about gvim is that I could cut a bunch of different snippets of code into named buffers, and paste them at will when doing something like repeating a common idiom.  For instance I'd have it so `"ap` would paste

```
DatabaseHandle handle = null;
try
{
  handle = DatabaseConnectionPool.newHandle();
```

and then `"bp` would paste

```
  handle.commit();
}
finally
{
  handle.rollback();
  DatabaseConnectionPool.returnHandle(handle);
}
```

And I could repeat both of them over and over in the course of a day.  In an answer to another question, somebody mentioned that you could "manage code snippets" in Eclipse, but didn't mention how.  So now I'm asking: how do you manage code snippets in Eclipse?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You might want to store those two snippets into a [code template](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2006/02/27/code-template-expansion-in-eclipse/), as explained in [this tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20140208040332/http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-add-your-own-code-template-in-eclipse.html).

And do not forget about the possibility to quickly execute any kind of java code snippets in a [scrapbook](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61137.html) (not exactly what you want, but it can come in handy at times)

[Newtopian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25812/newtopian) adds (in the comments)

> In fact templates become much more powerful by adding variables and tabstops within, so your example above would become **`dbHandle ctrl+space`**. It would copy snippets from both parts and place your cursor right in the middle.

Comment: I found a good video tutorial on how to make a snippet in Eclipse, its actually called a template there : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqMxaETAMaA&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 24):

Eclipse also offers something very similar to the templates feature described by VonC called (would you believe) snippets. Window > Show view > Snippets.

To add a new snippet category: Right click in the Snippets window and click Customize...
Click New > New Category. Enter a category name if necessary (e.g. "Java"). Click Apply. 
With your chosen category selected, click New > New Item. Enter your snippet.

To use a snippet, put the cursor where you want to insert the snippet, then double click on a snippet in the Snippets window.

Comment: is there a keyboard shortcut to use the snippet?

Comment: Does your variable substitution work - on my end the 'Insert Variable Placeholder...' button is disabled.

Comment: Ctrl-space is the shortcut.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the [Snip2Code](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/478177) plugin recently.
It did the job, and I can collect and search snippets in a quick way.

Comment: I installed Snip2code but not sure how to use it. How do I access it? I can't see it anywhere.

Comment: try to signup at http://www.snip2code.com/Access/Signup. Then, inside Eclipse, you would see a menu item "Snip2Code" to add new snippets to your account or search them

Answer (score 7):

Well a picture worths a thousand words, what about this one?

[image]

Comment: In the Eclipse 2019-12 version there's a "Context" button when you edit the template. Select Java to enable the template while editing Java code.

Answer (score 2):

The question is old but the link of the answere is older ;)

Here is a nice tutorial:
http://www.dansshorts.com/post/creating-snippets-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I have used snippets in some IDEs, like Dreamweaver and Homesite, an old Coldfusion IDE. I also use a lot of snippets in MySQL Workbench - where i type a lot of SQL, very handy there.

I am now using **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Version Indigo Release**  and found the snippets panel in **Window|Show View|Other...|General|Snippets**.  I was able to manipulate it and figure out how to add the code I wanted as snippets and how to use it efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Use Eclipse Snipmatch (Part of Eclipse for Java Developers Package).

- Works very well for Java code snippets but also works for any other language like HTML, ABABP, PHP etc.
- You can convert any code fragment from your editor directly to a code template. Highlight the code you'd like to convert to a snippet, context menu "create snippet", complete the form and done.
- snippets can be shared via Git repositories with your team members

Manual:
https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#snipmatch

Installation:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/snipmatch