# Quick way to insert the Java 'for' loop in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a (quick) way to automatically insert the Java `for` loop, for example, `for (int i=0;i< someInt;i++){` ?

It would be very convenient (as rest of code generation functionality).

Comment: can you be more explicit?

Comment: You could create a code snippet / template. See this SO post for more details... http://stackoverflow.com/q/237987/1246574

Comment: Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Templates

Comment: I think the question is explicit enough. Why those down votes? I really wonder why would someone downvote this.

Comment: @LeNoob If you want to know what was right/wrong about your question, you should make a post on meta.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Type `for` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Fast Code](http://www.3pintech.com/products/fast-code/) plugin or define your own template similar to [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA).

Someone has already posted some templates [here](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/03/30/declare-initialise-lists-maps-arrays-with-eclipse-templates/).