# Generate constructor using fields including null check using Objects.requireNonNull(T obj) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Constructors can be generated in eclipse quite easily. But, can the constructors somehow be generated which also perform null check? Example:

```
public class A {

    private B b;

    private C c;

    //I need to auto-generate this type of constructor for many of my classes in Eclipse  
    public A(B b, C c) {
         this.b = Objects.requireNonNull(b);
         this.c = Objects.requireNonNull(c); 
    }

}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

See tutorials like these :

[Link1](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/168-eclipse/1567-how-to-add-your-custom-controls-into-eclipse-palette.html) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237987/storing-code-snippets-in-eclipse)